# Meteor accounts login

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app has the insecure and autopublish removed and accounts-ui accounts-password added.
I am able to register a new user but how can I modify the app so that a user can send the username and password then my app invokes `isUserExist` and if `true` is returned, then the app logs this user in? Thanks

```
//client/login.html
<template name="login">
  {{> loginButtons}}
</template>

//client/login.js
Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
});

//server.js
Meteor.methods({
  isUserExist: function (username, password) {
   //do work
  return true; //or false
 }
});
```

Comment: Does [this](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/check-password) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the user document directly to the database, with the pre-issued username and password.
For this, you can either

1. build a new flow for the admin user (whoever will be creating those user-ids) to create the users, or
2. Insert the user details into the MongoDB database directly. This is not usually recommended because there might be dependencies / validations that you might miss, but it should work.

Comment: Please note the question update, use must first send credentials which are used as args in a server method that if returns true, this user gets validated and added to the database.

Comment: Samudra; what do you mean by "new flow"

Comment: Your edits seem to have changed the question, at least as I understood it. Have you looked at this package: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/ I think it does what you seek to do?